# Manage file upload to S3 bucket along with users who uploads the files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-transfer-family

Problem statement :
Manage file upload to S3 bucket along with users who uploads the files.

Approach:
By using the AWS Transfer Family, you can centralize and manage file uploads to an S3 bucket securely. We have control over user authentication, access permissions, and can track user activities. This allows us to build scalable and secure file transfer workflows while leveraging the services of S3.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**AWS transfer family specification**
(Source [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/transfer-service.html))

| Name | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Concurrent sessions per server | Each supported Region: 10,000 | Maximum number of concurrent sessions per server |
| File size | Each supported Region: 5 Terabytes | Maximum size of an individual file, which is the maximum size of an individual object in Amazon S3 |
| Idle connection timeout | Each supported Region: 1,800 Seconds i.e. 30 minutes | Inactivity timeout for SFTP connections. If there is no activity after the period has passed the client may be disconnected |
| MultiPart upload supported | No | SFTP server is primarily designed for simplified and secure file transfer workflows using SFTP protocols. |
| Resilience | Yes | SFTP protocol supports both reget and reput commands which allow you to resume downloads and uploads respectively. |

**AWS transfer family pricing :**
(Source [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/aws-transfer-family/pricing/))

| Components | Pricing |
| --- | --- |
| Time each protocol is enabled | $0.30 per hour per protocol |
| Data uploads | $0.04 per gigabyte (GB) transferred |
| Data downloads | $0.04 per gigabyte (GB) transferred |

**File size : Upload time using SFTP Vs. AWS CLI**

My home Upload speed : 103 Mbps and My home Download speed : 124 Mbps (megabits per second)

| File size | Upload time from local machine using SFTP | Upload time from local machine using AWS CLI |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 211 KB | 0.01 seconds | 3 seconds |
| 500 MB | 3 minutes and 45 seconds | 32 seconds |
| 1 GB | 5 minutes and 13 seconds | 48 seconds |
| 5 GB | 22 minutes and 49 seconds | 3 minutes and 27 seconds |
| 10 GB | 39 minutes and 04 seconds | 6 minutes and 45 seconds |